# How to make adjacency matrix for sub-graphs detected by leidenalg

Tags: python, graph, igraph, adjacency-matrix

I need to make adjacency matrix for each community(sub-graph) detected by leidenalg;  but the problem is  the output of find_partition() is just showing the nodes in each sub-graph. Is there any way to convert the output to something like np.array with edge information of each sub-graph??

```
import leidenalg
import igraph as ig

G = ig.Graph.Erdos_Renyi(10, 0.1);
partitions = leidenalg.find_partition(G, leidenalg.ModularityVertexPartition)
print(partitions)
```

output:

```
Clustering with 10 elements and 3 clusters
[0] 2, 5, 8, 9
[1] 3, 4, 6
[2] 0, 1, 7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by simply constructing the subgraph and the computing the adjacency matrix.   Your example is not quite reproducible because `ig.Graph.Erdos_Renyi` uses the random number generator. Therefore, I added a little code to set the random seed and generate a graph like yours, except reproducible. I simply get the adjacency matrix for the first partition, but of course,  you can just loop through the partitions and get all of the matrices.

```
import igraph as ig
import leidenalg
import random

random.seed(a=321)
G = ig.Graph.Erdos_Renyi(10, 0.28);
partitions = leidenalg.find_partition(G, leidenalg.ModularityVertexPartition)
print(partitions)

P0 = G.subgraph(partitions[0])
P0.get_adjacency()

Out[15]: Matrix([[0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0]])
```